# How do I change a VCL unit in Delphi (XE2)?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I found a workaround for a bug [(QC#25702)](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=25702) in the Delphi VCL unit Grids.pas, so I copied that file to my project's source folder, added it to the project and changed a few lines of code. That was with Delphi 2007, and everything worked as expected.

Now, with Delphi XE2, the project no longer compiles. It complains about incompatible types "TCustomGrid" and "TdzVirtualStringGrid" (which is a descendant of TCustomGrid). It turns out that one unit refers to TCustomGrid as declared in my copy of Grids.pas, the other to TCustomGrid as declared in Vcl.Grids.pas. This happens even though both units have "Grids" in their uses clause (rather than Vcl.Grids). Any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: The process you describe is known to work. So clearly some specific detail has gone awry. Some specific is incorrect. We can only guess at what that could be. Is there an out-of-date dcu file perhaps? Or maybe you added the D2007 `Grids` (with mods) to the XE2 project. Try and do some debugging to look for the specific environmental issue.

Comment: I was just about to repeat the process with the Vcl.Grids unit from XE2 (putting it in a different subdirectory to include it only for the XE2 version of the project). As it turned out, the bug was apparently fixed in XE2, so I just removed the Grids unit from the project, moved the Delphi 2007 file to a subdirectory and included it only in the Delphi 2007 version of the project.

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't explain why within the same project apparently both units were used. Deleting all dcu files didn't help but because I use the modified unit only in Delphi 2007 now, the error is gone. So, how do I close this question? It's not really answered but no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are including the Delphi 2007 `Grids` unit in your XE2 project. That won't work at all. What you need to do to modify an RTL/VCL unit in this way is as follows:

1. Start with the source code for the unit supplied with the Delphi version that you are using. In this case start with `Vcl.Grids.pas` supplied with XE2.
2. Make a copy of that unit inside your project directory, and add that unit to your project.
3. Make any modifications to the implementation section of the copied unit.

Comment: Actually, it works. I had just accidentally added the Grids.pas file from the subdirectory meant for the Delphi 2007 version to the project for the XE2 version. The XE2 project compiled with just a few warnings in that unit. The warnings were the only thing that told me of my mistake.

Comment: The D2007 version might compile, but it won't work properly at runtime.

Comment: FWIW, since you are not allowed to distribute that unit under that name, I would personally change the name of the unit, and I would even change the names of the classes used. Just to avoid confusion once you upgrade. And David is right: it is not a good idea to use a D2007 unit, especially since that is a pre-Unicode unit.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis you can't change the name because then this trick doesn't work at all

Comment: I usually install the newly named component and use that instead of the original component (name).

Comment: @rudy we are talking about different things

Comment: I was talking about taking the source of the original unit, changing its name and the names of the classes, modifying the code to remove the bug and using it in my project instead of the original, "buggy" unit. If the unit contains several components, I even remove the ones I don't want to modify. That way, the original can be used alongside the corrected and renamed unit.

Comment: @rudy We were talking about something else